# How to schedule repeatable sequences of tasks

Tags: org-mode

I've been trying to find the right approach of scheduling a repeatable sequence of tasks:

1. first approach was to mark the parent as repeatable and children as normal tasks.

   ```
   * TODO This is the parent task
   SCHEDULED <2020-01-01 Wed ++1w>
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ORDERED:  t
   :END:
   ** TODO This is 1st subtask
   ** TODO This is 2nd subtask
   ```

   The downside of this approach is that once marking the parent task as done, I need to manually change the state of the child tasks back to **TODO**.
2. the second approach I have tried is to mark both the parent and child tasks as repeating.  This approach doesn't work (at all) as the parent can never be marked as DONE.

   *(This behavior led to the 3rd approach)*
3. in the third approach, only the child tasks are marked as repeating.  The parent task is never marked as DONE (it's not possible) and it actually never shows up in agendas either.

Are there other approaches?  Can I improve on any of the approached above?

thank you

Comment: This is a good question, and it highlights some known deficiencies in the inheritance structure of Org tasks. You might want to look into `org-depend` as another means of making tasks trigger each other. I imagine that it will end up looking pretty clunky. Hopefully somebody can respond more authoritatively to this.

Comment: I ended up using `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` for such things. It creates a given number of copies of the subtree with the desired time-shift. See https://karl-voit.at/2017/01/15/org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift/